# Why numberOfSectionsInTableView get called so many time (4 times) without doing anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UIViewController with UITableView as subview, when I set breakpoint in `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` I expected it to called just one, but turn out it get called 4 time.

Here is part of related code

```
#define FunctionLog NSLog(@"<%@:%@:%d>", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), __LINE__);


#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    FunctionLog
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    FunctionLog
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FunctionLog
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"basicCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell number %ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

and here is the log

```
2015-07-03 16:54:24.528 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:numberOfSectionsInTableView::34>
2015-07-03 16:54:25.527 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:tableView:numberOfRowsInSection::40>
2015-07-03 16:54:25.527 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:numberOfSectionsInTableView::34>
2015-07-03 16:54:40.467 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:tableView:numberOfRowsInSection::40>
2015-07-03 16:54:40.469 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:numberOfSectionsInTableView::34>
2015-07-03 16:54:42.724 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:tableView:numberOfRowsInSection::40>
2015-07-03 16:54:42.724 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:numberOfSectionsInTableView::34>
2015-07-03 16:54:43.994 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:tableView:numberOfRowsInSection::40>
2015-07-03 16:54:43.994 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath::46>
2015-07-03 16:54:43.998 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath::46>
2015-07-03 16:54:43.999 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath::46>
2015-07-03 16:54:44.000 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath::46>
2015-07-03 16:54:44.000 [20394:1570424] <ViewController:tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath::46>
```

Comment: Cocoa Touch magic :D